# How can I show the commit date when using git rev-list --oneline?

Tags: git

I'm trying to get a listing of the commits + commit date for a branch with:

```
git rev-list --oneline --first-parent --date=short --reverse HEAD
```

From the [documentation](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-rev-list#Documentation/git-rev-list.txt---dateltformatgt), showing a date requires `--pretty` format, which outputs multiple lines. How can I show the commit date when using the `--oneline` option?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Git provides [multiple formatting options](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-rev-list#Documentation/git-rev-list.txt-emnem) that you can pass to the `pretty` command to pick out the different pieces of the commit you want to display

For instance if you just want to grab the shortened commit hash (%H for the full commit hash) you could use:

`git rev-list --pretty='format:%h' HEAD`

To add the commit subject:

`git rev-list --pretty='format:%h %s' HEAD`

And the shortened date:

`git rev-list --pretty='format:%h %s %ad' --date=short HEAD`

You can also add some pretty color formatting if you wish:

`git rev-list --pretty='format:%C(auto)%h %s %ad' --date=short HEAD`

All of which is just C style string formatting so you can add pipes or commas as you see fit:

`git rev-list --pretty='format:%C(auto)%h | %s | %ad' --date=short HEAD`

To remove the intermediate line containing the full commit hash you can pipe the output to sed/awk:

`git rev-list --pretty='format:%C(auto)%h | %s | %ad' --first-parent --reverse --date=short HEAD | awk 'NR%2==0'`

Comment: Excellent commands!  Though, with the last one, we do lose the colors... because of the pipe to awk... Is there a solution for that?

Answer (score 1):

Use `git log` instead:

```
git log --oneline --first-parent --format="%h %cd" HEAD
```

Answer (score 0):

Kinda slow and not ideal but you can do something like this:

```
git rev-list --oneline --first-parent --reverse HEAD | awk '{cmd="git show -s --format=%ci "$1" | cat"; cmd | getline t; print $0 " " t}'
```